# Undefined variable in Routing (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I wanted to minimize my URL but I am having a problem. My route in Routes.php looks like this:

```
$route["news/(:num)"] = "home/news/$news";
```

In `Home` controller I have `news` function which takes a paramater `$news`. 
This is working `http://localhost/bestcarsinfo/home/news/7`

But when I use new URL version `http://localhost/bestcarsinfo/news/7`
I am getting error saying:

> Undefined variable: news`in`config/routes.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as the error says, $news is undefined. The router uses the $1 (or other numeric values) as a reference in the replacement for the **regex** that parses the route, you can't pass it arbitarty variables.

it should be:

```
$route["news/(:num)"] = "home/news/$1";
```

A snippet from the Router.php core class:

```
if (preg_match('#^'.$key.'$#', $uri))
{
   // Do we have a back-reference?
   if (strpos($val, '$') !== FALSE AND strpos($key, '(') !== FALSE)
   {
      $val = preg_replace('#^'.$key.'$#', $val, $uri);
   }
   return $this->_set_request(explode('/', $val));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working, but I don't understand the idea itself. My function should take paramater $news. Here I am writing $1. Or is $1 something default variable?

Comment: `$1` is a reference for the `1st` element that matches the regex (in this case, `(:num)` ). You don't pass the actual variable, since the router doesn't know and doesn't care.